# How is the force reload of javascript/css done in Symfony?

Tags: php, javascript, css, caching, symfony-1.4

After reading this thread: [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

I would like to know if there is any built-in function  or easy way in Symfony that automatically forces a reload by appending a random querystring or timestamp to the link when it has discovered that javascript / css file has been modified. (Normally, people use the `use_javascript` function to generate the `<script>` tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism, but a little creativity means you can do this just about anywhere in your code, from view.yml to layout.php to each individual action.

The view.yml method is easy enough:

*apps/frontend/config/view.yml:*

```
  stylesheets:    [main?v=<?php echo time() ?>, reset?v=<?php echo time() ?>, layout?v=<?php echo time() ?>]
```

Although I think this is a little too active, and I tend to use either the SVN revision or a overall project version number:

```
  stylesheets:    [main?v=<?php echo sfConfig('app_project_version') ?>, reset?v=<?php echo sfConfig('app_project_version') ?>, layout?v=<?php echo sfConfig('app_project_version') ?>]
```

where `app_project_version` is set in *apps/frontend/config/app.yml*. Methods for layout.php and actionSuccess.php should be easy enough from here:

```
<?php use_stylesheet('blah?v='.sfConfig::get('app_project_version')); ?>
```

Comment: But this would only have effects when using include_javascript / include_stylesheet. In my Symfony application, view.yml is not used at all, the use_javascript and use_stylesheet functions are used instead.

Comment: The principle is the same - these functions are practically synonyms for each other, just used in different contexts (YAML and PHP).

In your case, simply use:

    `<?php use_stylesheet('blah?v='.sfConfig::get('app_version')); ?>`

I have updated the answer with this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end, I adopted your idea and modified the javascript_path and stylesheet_path functions in AssetHelper.php of the framework to make this possible. But I would have to keep this in mind when doing the version upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

instead of setting a version for each stylesheet you include, it is better to have it done automatically for all included stylesheets, no matter if you use view.yml or use_stylesheet() method. You need to implement this helper method and
include the helper in your applications settings.yml, so that it becomes available to alle your actions.

`

```
function include_versioned_stylesheets()
{
    $response = sfContext::getInstance()->getResponse();
    sfConfig::set('symfony.asset.stylesheets_included', true);
    $html = '';
    foreach ($response->getStylesheets() as $file => $options) {
        $filepath = sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir') . '/' .  stylesheet_path($file);
        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            $file .= '?v=' . filectime($filepath);
        }
        $html .= stylesheet_tag($file, $options);
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

`

in your layout.php call this inside your header area. make sure there is no further call to include_stylesheets(), as this is an extended version to it. 
same can be done with include_javascripts.

Comment: the best sollution i think, but i used it with filemtime() and in prod env only. Thanks